# Migrating SOLR fq to Elasticsearch

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

I am currently migrating a SOLR app to Elasticsearch and have become stuck on a particular query. The ElasticSearch documentation is rather vague on how to achieve my desired result. 
Currently I am trying to convert tagged "fq's" (filter queries) from SOLR into Elasticsearch. I need to be able to return from Elasticsearch facets (now known as aggregations) based on my query and filters but also show aggregations for other options in a search

Although this sounds complicated it is achieved in SOLR simply by adding an "fq" parameter and tagging the filter as follows:

```
q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&facet=on&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype
```

From the main SOLR help docs this will filter on "doctype:pdf" but also include counts for other doc types in the facet output - again this works fine for me, I am simply trying to recreate this in Elasticsearch.

So far I have tried a "post_filter" which does the job until I wish to apply anymore than one filter (again something SOLR handles with no problems). You can see an example of how this works and how I want to achieve it at:

[https://www.jobsinhealthcare.co.uk/search?latitude=&longitude=&title=&location=&radius=5&type=&salary=0&frequency=year&since=&jobtype=&keywords=&company=&sort=Most+recent&filter[contract_type_estr][33d5667c]=Temporary&filter[job_type_estr][5d370027]=Part+time&filter[job_type_estr][4b45bd05]=Full+time](https://www.jobsinhealthcare.co.uk/search?latitude=&longitude=&title=&location=&radius=5&type=&salary=0&frequency=year&since=&jobtype=&keywords=&company=&sort=Most%20recent&filter[contract_type_estr][33d5667c]=Temporary&filter[job_type_estr][5d370027]=Part%20time&filter[job_type_estr][4b45bd05]=Full%20time)

IN the filters/facets on the Right of the results you can select multiple "contract type" and/or "job type" and/or "location" and still be shown the facet counts for unselected queries/filters. Please note that Hourly Salary, Annual Salary and Date Added do NOT have this functionality - this is by design.

Any pointers as to how I should be structuring my query would be greatly apprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is global aggregation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html). Inside top level aggregation you should use filter aggregation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) as a sub-aggretation to filter only "status:public".

Comment: I don't want a global aggregation, I want it to respect the search criteria but also offer the other suggestions. A global aggregation would be silly in my case as the facets would have no context whatsoever.